# Dynamic row insert after php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, input

I have a dynamic row input when I click on a `plus` button. But my rows are added in the top of my page and I wish them to be added after my first row. Here is my code:

```
<?php
 ?>
<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">
    <form method="post">
    <div id="itemRows">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'"> <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
$( "name[]" ).insertAfter( "#add_name" );
}
function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
```

And here is my input:

```
<b>Dimanche</b> </br><?php echo $date1 ?>   
        </td>
        <!-- numéro de projet du dimanche -->
        <td>
            <span id="numpro" >
                <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;">

                    <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="+" /> 
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="add_name"onkeypress="return handleEnter(event, this, 'task');"/>

                    <?php
                        if($result!=false && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                            while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
                    ?>
                                <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>">  <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" /> <input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
                            <?php
                            endwhile;

                            }
                            ?>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery's .append() method to add elements one after another within particular tag.

Change your code with below line:

```
$( "name[]" ).append( "#add_name" );
```

Comment: don't work they always add at the top of my page  and this line of my code don't work too : $( "name[]" ).insertAfter( "#add_name" );

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.after` function in jQuery to append after a specific element
https://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

The append function / insertAfter will works.

But in your code you have used element property directly as

`$( "name[]" ).insertAfter( "#add_name" );` or

```
$( "name[]" ).append( "#add_name" );
```

Instead, you need to use following :

1. **Change the name value** of textbox "name[]" to some other name say for example "name_test" and append it after "add_name"
2. Also you have used "add_name" as an id `( "#add_name" )` but it is a **name attribute** of input text box.
3. And you need to **append the entire row** created in `row` varaible after "add_name"
   You need to change code as

`$("input[name=add_name]" ).after(row);`

But, it still add on top of each element i.e. in stack fashion.

Hence, you need to **go through "add_name" parent** i.e form and **append within that parent** as

```
$( "input[name=add_name]" ).parent().append(row);
```

And It should work :)

Here is the **[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/MeuW4/)** for above scenario.

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon, did you try this?